# Best way to make 3D model out of CT scans with python?

Tags: python, 3d, blender

I want to make a 3D model from the heart by using CT scans. I used Blender but it didn't work out well. This Python script is running too slow. Does someone know a better way to do this?

```
import bpy
import os
import pydicom
import numpy as np

path = "./Desktop/EMC/"

files = sorted(os.listdir(path + "/Data/Head/"))  

data = np.zeros((245, 512, 512)) 

for i in range(len(files)):
    layer = pydicom.dcmread(path + "/Data/Head/" + files[i]) # read dcm files

    data[i] = layer.pixel_array 

for yy in range(245):
    for xx in range(512):
        for zz in range(512):
            print("X: {}, Y: {}, Z: {}".format(xx, yy, zz))

            c = data[yy, xx, zz]



            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(xx / 500, zz / 500, yy / 500))
            bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0.001, 0.001, 0.001))

            activeObject = bpy.context.active_object # Select active object 
            mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="MaterialName") 
            activeObject.data.materials.append(mat) #Add Material

            bpy.context.object.active_material.diffuse_color = (c, c, c) #change color

            if zz == 511:        #Join objects and remove doubles
                item='MESH'
                bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
                bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type=item)
                bpy.ops.object.join()

                bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
                bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles()
                bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

print("DONE")
```

Comment: Add the voxel data as a volume texture, apply it to a cube, configure a volumetric material (normally used for fog, clouds or such), use that and call it a day. Meshes are a crude representation of geometry anyway, and the only reason, why you'd want to perform image to mesh segmentation in the first place is, if you need some tesselated representation of the data. Otherwise: Don't bother.

Comment: [this may interest you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/48919/935).  As shown in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14846/935) , creating lots of objects is slow, it will be mush faster if you create all the cubes in the same mesh object.

Answer (score 0):

Blender is [faster with one object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14846/935) that has one million vertices than if it had 1000 objects of 1000 vertices each. Rather than creating multiple cubes and joining them together, use [bmesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html) to add multiple cubes within the one mesh object.

Another consideration is the [use of operators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7358/935), each operator call does a scene update and redraw, by working directly with mesh data and then doing one update you prevent a lot of unneeded updates.

Using random colours instead of ct images, the following script runs in about 10% of the time. I also made the cubes bigger, if the initial cubes are too small, remove doubles can merge more than what you want, you can always scale it down after building the mesh.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import mathutils
import numpy as np

# replace these two lines with your data filling code
x_size = y_size = z_size = 10
data = np.random.rand(x_size, y_size, z_size)

me = bpy.data.meshes.new("Mesh_new")
scene = bpy.context.scene
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("CT_Scan_new", me)
scene.objects.link(obj)
scene.objects.active = obj
obj.select = True

bm = bmesh.new()

for yy in range(y_size):
    for xx in range(x_size):
        for zz in range(z_size):
            c = data[yy, xx, zz]
            bmesh.ops.create_cube(bm, size=0.1,
                    matrix=mathutils.Matrix.Translation((xx / 10, zz / 10, yy / 10)))
            mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="MaterialName")
            mat.diffuse_color = (c, c, c)
            obj.data.materials.append(mat)
            mat_idx = len(obj.data.materials)-1
            bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
            for i in range(6):
                # assign the last material to the last six faces created
                bm.faces[-i].material_index = mat_idx

bmesh.ops.remove_doubles(bm, verts=bm.verts, dist=0.001)
bm.to_mesh(me)
```

Comment: This post could does not answer the question.

Comment: @ArihanSharma they asked for a better solution, this script does the same thing in 10% of the time - how is that not answering the question?

Comment: Well, you see, it *does* sort of answer the question, but not really, as you are using the same *way*, only the code is different. However, I *will* remove my downvote, but you will have to edit it as now my vote is locked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this *without ANY Python!* Just use Meshroom.